# Understanding of diff output

Tags: linux, files, diff

I have `file1.txt`

```
this is the original text  
line2  
line3  
line4  
happy hacking !
```

and `file2.txt`

```
this is the original text  
line2  
line4  
happy hacking !  
GNU is not UNIX
```

if I do: `diff file1.txt file2.txt` I get:

```
3d2  
< line3  
5a5  
> GNU is not UNIX
```

How is the output generally interpreted? I think that `<` means removed but what do `3d2` or `5a5` mean?

If I do:

```bash
$ diff -u file1.txt file2.txt  
--- file1.txt        2013-07-06 17:44:59.180000000 +0200  
+++ file2.txt        2013-07-06 17:39:53.433000000 +0200  
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@  
 this is the original text  
 line2  
-line3  
 line4  
 happy hacking !  
+GNU is not UNIX
```

The results are clearer but what does `@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@` mean?

Answer (score 220):

In your first `diff` output (so called "normal diff") the meaning is as follows:

`<` - denotes lines in file1.txt

`>` - denotes lines in file2.txt

`3d2` and `5a5` denote line numbers affected and which actions were performed. `d` stands for deletion, `a` stands for adding (and `c` stands for changing). the number on the left of the character is the line number in file1.txt, the number on the right is the line number in file2.txt. So `3d2` tells you that the 3rd line in file1.txt was deleted and has the line number 2 in file2.txt (or better to say that after deletion the line counter went back to line number 2). `5a5` tells you that the we started from line number 5 in file1.txt (which was actually empty after we deleted a line in previous action), added the line and this added line is the number 5 in file2.txt.

The output of `diff -u` command is formatted a bit differently (so called "unified diff" format). Here `diff` shows us a single piece of the text, instead of two separate texts. In the line `@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@` the part `-1,5` relates to file1.txt and the part `+1,5` to file2.txt. They tell us that `diff` will show a piece of text, which is 5 lines long starting from line number 1 in file1.txt. And the same about the file2.txt - `diff` shows us 5 lines starting from line 1.

As I have already said, the lines from both files are shown together

```
 this is the original text  
 line2  
-line3  
 line4  
 happy hacking !  
+GNU is not UNIX
```

Here `-` denotes the lines which were deleted from file1.txt, and `+` denotes the lines which were added.

Comment: For completeness in the last paragraph: a space ' ' at the start of a line shows it is unchanged.

Comment: While it's easy enough to find online diff apps, are there any online diff-file app that provides visual cues to diff files?

Comment: @Konchog not sure about online services, but out of desktop apps I like `meld` most.

Comment: @JohnSmith, yeah I was looking for a patch file viewer, not a diff app.

Comment: @JohnSmith Can you elaborate on "after deletion the line counter went back to line number 2" for `3d2`?

Comment: @adosar before deleting the line you're on the line 3 (the line counter is 3), after deleting the line it gets back you to the line 2 (the counter is 2). This is how I understand it

Answer (score 45):

**Summary**:

Given a `diff file1 file2`, `<` means the line is missing in `file2` and `>`means the line is missing in `file1`. The `3d2` and `5a5` can be ignored, they are commands for `patch` which is often used with `diff`.

**Full Answer**:

Many *nix utilities offer TeXinfo manuals as well as the simpler `man` pages. you can access these by running `info command`, for example `info diff`. In this case, the section your are interested in is:

> 

### 2.4.2 Detailed Description of Normal Format

> The normal output format consists of one or more hunks of differences;
> each hunk shows one area where the files differ.  Normal format hunks
> look like this:

```
 CHANGE-COMMAND
 < FROM-FILE-LINE
 < FROM-FILE-LINE...
 ---
 > TO-FILE-LINE
 > TO-FILE-LINE...
```

> There are three types of change commands.  Each consists of a line
> number or comma-separated range of lines in the first file, a single
> character indicating the kind of change to make, and a line number or
> comma-separated range of lines in the second file.  All line numbers
> are the original line numbers in each file.  The types of change
> commands are:

```
`LaR'
     Add the lines in range R of the second file after line L of the
     first file.  For example, `8a12,15' means append lines 12-15 of
     file 2 after line 8 of file 1; or, if changing file 2 into file 1,
     delete lines 12-15 of file 2.

`FcT'
     Replace the lines in range F of the first file with lines in range
     T of the second file.  This is like a combined add and delete, but
     more compact.  For example, `5,7c8,10' means change lines 5-7 of
     file 1 to read as lines 8-10 of file 2; or, if changing file 2 into
     file 1, change lines 8-10 of file 2 to read as lines 5-7 of file 1.

`RdL'
     Delete the lines in range R from the first file; line L is where
     they would have appeared in the second file had they not been 
     deleted.  For example, '5,7d3' means delete lines 5-7 of file 1;
     or, if changing file 2 into file 1, append lines 5-7 of file1
     after line 3 of file 2.
```

Comment: To make sure I understand this: if you were to swap `file1` and `file2`, would all `XaY` become `YdX`, `XcY` become `YcX`, and `XdY` become `YaX`?

Comment: @BallpointBen more likely the differences listed will change in order. It's much easier to understand if you just create a couple of files to play with.

Answer (score 13):

**1) Rename the file parameters to help you remember what's going on like this:**

Rather than:

```
diff f1 f2    # f1=file 1, and f2=file2
```

think

```
diff file-to-edit file-with-updates
```

The results by default come from **file-to-edit**, with updates from **file-with-updates**.

---

**2) Also these command renames might help you think about what is happening:**

**d** stands for **d**elete, but '**remove**' is more clearly what happens
**a** stands for **a**dd, ...... but '**insert**' is more clearly what happens

**c** stands for **c**hange = **d** + **a** or 'remove + insert'.

---

**Used like this:**

2,4**d**1 or in general D(s)-**d**-N = **d**elete ('**remove**') D line(s).  Then sync at line N in both.

4**a**2,4 or in general N-**a**-U(s) = At line N, **a**dd ('**insert**') update-line(s) U.

*Note:  Parameters for these two are nearly symmetric; just reversed left to right.*

---

2,4**c**5,6 or in general R(s)-**c**-U(s) = Remove R(s) lines, then insert updated lines U(s) in their place.

---

**For example:**

4**a**2,4 means starting at 4, add (insert) updated lines 2-4 *(i.e. "2,4" means lines 2, 3 and 4)*

2,4**d**1 means remove lines 2-4 (2, 3 and 4).

2,4**c**5,6 means remove lines 2-4 (2, 3 and 4), and insert updated lines 5-6 (5 and 6).

Answer (score 9):

The above answers are good. However as a beginner, I found them slightly difficult to understand and upon searching further, I found a very useful link:
[Linux Diff Command & Examples](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm)

The site explains the concept in a simple and easy to understand manner.

Diff command is easier to understand if you consider it this way :

> Essentially, it outputs a set of instructions for how to change one
>   file to make it identical to the second file.

Each of the following cases are explained well:

> a for add, c for change, d for delete

Answer (score 7):

I suggest to use:

`diff -rupP file1.txt file2.txt > result.patch`

Then, when you read `result.patch`, you will instantly know the difference.

These are the meanings of the command line switches:

**-r**: recursive

**-u**: shows line number

**-p**(small): shows differences in C functions

**-P**(capital): in case of multiple files the full path is  shown

Comment: `diff -rupP file1.txt file2.txt | vim -` this will display with highlight

Comment: If you're piping to`vim`, may want to just go directly to `vimdiff file_one file_two`.