# Result of diff two files with switched lines says missing the same line twice

Tags: diff

I am trying to understand the linux diff command on two files whose lines are just permutation of each other but not able to grok the output that it generates. Consider the three commands below:

```
[myPrompt]$ cat file1
apples
oranges
[myPrompt]$ cat file2 
oranges
apples
[myPrompt]$ diff file1 file2
1d0
< apples
2a2
> apples
```

Can someone explain the above cryptic output from diff.

1. Why there is no mention of "oranges" at all in the output?
2. What does `1d0` and `2a2` mean?

I understand [from this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82004/28032) that :

> "<" means the line is missing in file2 and ">" means the line is missing in
>   file1

BUT that doesn't explain why oranges is missing in the output.

Comment: Because `oranges` is the largest common part between the two files, so what you obtain is the shortest way to express the differences between the two.

Comment: And if you want more readable output, just use `diff -u file1 file2` instead.  That's called "unified diff" format.  The original diff format was meant to be very compact, but unified diffs are meant to be much more readable.

Comment: @godlygeek Or `diff -y file1 file2`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To understand the report, remember that `diff` is prescriptive, describing what changes need to be made to the first file (`file1`) to make it the same as the second file (`file2`).

Specifically, the `d` in `1d0` means *delete* and the `a` in `2a2` means *add*.

Thus:

- `1d0` means line 1 must be deleted in `file1` (`apples`). `0` in `1d0` means line 0 is where they would have appeared in the second file (`file2`) had they not been deleted. That means when changing `file2` to `file1` (backwards) append line 1 of `file1` after line 0 of `file2`.
- `2a2` means append the second line (`oranges`) from `file2` to the now second line of `file1` (after deleting the first line in `file1`, `oranges` switched to line 1)

Comment: what is `0` in `1d0`?

Comment: @Geek see my edit

Comment: @Geek But be careful, that can make knots in the brain =)

Comment: that has, indeed started making knots :-)

Answer (score 14):

Consider these files:

`file1`:

```
# cat file1
apples
pears
oranges
peaches
```

`file2`:

```
# cat file2
oranges
apples
peaches
ananas
banana
```

How `diff` works, given it is order-based:

1. `diff` reads the first block of lines of `file1` and `file2`, and tries to find equal lines:

   ```
     file1        file2        differences on left (<) or right side (>)
     apples                   <apples
     pears                    <pears 
     -------------------------------
   ->oranges    ->oranges
     peaches      apples
                  peaches
                  ananas
                  banana
   ```
2. Now it will skip all lines that are equal in both files, which is just `oranges` in this case:

   ```
     file1        file2        differences on left (<) or right side (>)
     apples                   <apples
     pears                    <pears 
     oranges      oranges
     -------------------------------
   ->peaches    ->apples
                  peaches
                  ananas
                  banana
   ```
3. Now find another set of similar lines and print out differences:

   ```
     file1        file2        differences on left (<) or right side (>)
     apples                   <apples
     pears                    <pears 
     oranges      oranges
                  apples      >apples
     -------------------------------
   ->peaches    ->peaches
                  ananas
                  banana
   ```
4. Skip the similar lines

   ```
     file1        file2        differences on left (<) or right side (>)
     apples                   <apples
     pears                    <pears 
     oranges      oranges
                  apples      >apples
     peaches      peaches
     -------------------------------
   ->           ->ananas
                  banana
   ```
5. Find identical lines, if possible, and print differences:

   ```
   line_file1    file1    line_file2    file2        differences on left (<) or right side (>)
            1    apples                              <apples 
            2    pears                               <pears 
            3    oranges           1    oranges
                                   2    apples       >apples
            4    peaches           3    peaches
                                   4    ananas       >ananas
                                   5    banana       >banana
            -----------------------------------------------
   ```

Now if I do `diff file1 file2`:

```
# diff file1 file2
1,2d0
< apples
< pears
3a2
> apples
4a4,5
> ananas
> banana
```

Now it is simple to explain what `diff`'s output means:

To make `file1` equal to `file2`:

- `1,2d0`: **Delete** (`d`) lines `1-2` from `file1` and modify line `0` of `file2` accordingly
- `3a2`: **Append** (`a`) to line `3` of `file1` line `2` of `file2`
- `4a4,5`: **Append** to line `4` of `file1` lines `4-5` of `file2`

`diff` compares `file1` with `file2` line by line and settles differences in temporary memory. After making `file1` **equal to** `file2` until the first occurrence of a line in `file1`, which also occurs in `file2`, all lines that are equal up until a difference are not mentioned, often indicated as `---`. In this case there is only one similar line, which is `oranges`. Note that I said `file1` equal to `file2`, so `file1` is viewed relative to `file2` and not the other way around.

The output is in relation to the first file given, in this case `file1`.

Comment: I don't like the initial explanation: `apples` occurs in both files just as well.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I changed the explanation. Does it sound more clear/better now :)?

Comment: Not quite, for now you wrote "there is only one similar line, which is `oranges`". Wrong: There are actually *two* lines, which are not only *similar*, but absolutely *identical*. One of them reads `oranges`, the other one reads `apples`. Also, your explanation (purely order-based) is in contradiction to [Stéphane](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas)'s comment on the question (length-based) - who is correct?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You forgot "In this case" and the lines before that. I meant it in this step there is only one similar line. I will just add an example to my answer so that it can be understood better.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Also can you give me an example that shows that the length-based answer is correct?

Comment: I read your answer several times, and I always instinctively understood *in this case* as "in this case, where there are two identical lines in the two files, `apples` and `oranges`. As for the length-based answer, where do I claim that it is correct? I am merely pointing out that the length-based explanation (from a comment that was upvoted six times and not disputed a single time) is in contrast to your explanation, so I asked which one is correct.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper With my example, is it now clear? If it is still unclear, please just edit my answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 8):

There they are:

```
$ diff file1 file2
1d0
< apples
2a2
> apples
$ diff file2 file1
1d0
< oranges
2a2
> oranges
```

Answer (score 8):

The standard (old) output format will display the difference between the files without surrounding text with areas where the files differ.

For example: `1d0 <` (delete) means the *apples* needs to be removed from the 1st line of `file1`, and `2a2 >` (append) means the *apples* needs to be added into `file2` on the 2nd line, so both files can be matched.

Documentation available at `info diff` explains it further more:

> **Showing Differences Without Context**
>
> The "normal" `diff` output format shows each hunk of differences without any surrounding context.  Sometimes such output is the clearest way to see how lines have changed, without the clutter of nearby unchanged lines (although you can get similar results with the context or unified formats by using 0 lines of context).  However, this format is no longer widely used for sending out patches; for that purpose, the context format and the unified format are superior.
>   Normal format is the default for compatibility with older versions of `diff` and the POSIX standard. Use the `--normal` option to select this output format explicitly.
>
> **Detailed Description of Normal Format**
>
> The normal output format consists of one or more hunks of
>   differences; each hunk shows one area where the files differ.  Normal
>   format hunks look like this:
>
> ```
>  CHANGE-COMMAND
>  < FROM-FILE-LINE
>  < FROM-FILE-LINE...
>  ---
>  > TO-FILE-LINE
>  > TO-FILE-LINE...
> ```
>
> There are three types of change commands.  Each consists of a line
>   number or comma-separated range of lines in the first file, a single
>   character indicating the kind of change to make, and a line number or
>   comma-separated range of lines in the second file.  All line numbers
>   are the original line numbers in each file.  The types of change
>   commands are:
>
> `LaR`
>        Add the lines in range R of the second file after line L of the
>        first file.  For example, `8a12,15` means append lines 12-15 of
>        file 2 after line 8 of file 1; or, if changing file 2 into file 1,
>        delete lines 12-15 of file 2.
>
> `FcT`
>        Replace the lines in range F of the first file with lines in range
>        T of the second file.  This is like a combined add and delete, but
>        more compact.  For example, `5,7c8,10` means change lines 5-7 of
>        file 1 to read as lines 8-10 of file 2; or, if changing file 2 into
>        file 1, change lines 8-10 of file 2 to read as lines 5-7 of file 1.
>
> `RdL`
>        Delete the lines in range R from the first file; line L is where
>        they would have appeared in the second file had they not been
>        deleted.  For example, `5,7d3` means delete lines 5-7 of file 1;
>        or, if changing file 2 into file 1, append lines 5-7 of file 1
>        after line 3 of file 2.

See also:

- [Linux diff Command Explained With Examples](http://linoxide.com/linux-command/linux-diff-command-examples/)
- [Understanding of diff output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81998/understaning-of-diff-output)

---

So to see the oranges, you would have to diff it either by side by side or by using unified context.

In example:

```
$ diff -y file1 file2
apples                                <
oranges                             oranges
                                  > apples

$ diff -u file1 file2
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-apples
 oranges
+apples
```