# What do these codes in 'diff' mean and how to get rid of them?

Tags: text-processing, diff, file-comparison

I am using `diff` to find difference from current file to a target.

The command I have is
`diff -w --from-file /tmp/new_list.txt /tmp/protected_client.txt`

The output is

```
8c8,9
> VM-E
```

I filtered this using:
`diff -w --from-file /tmp/new_list.txt /tmp/protected_client.txt | tail -n +2 | sed 's/> //g'`

Great. Now, If I have multiple differences, the  I see:

```
2d1
< esxi02
3a3
> psc-dr
```

Two questions. What are these values.
I know `<` means value is there in `from-file` but not in `to-file` and `>` is the reverse,

Second question: how do I get rid of these codes `2d1` and `3a3` or whatever comes up.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81998/understanding-of-diff-output

Answer (score 11):

Those codes give you a line number and a type of difference which has been found:

- `a` stands for added
- `c` changed
- `d` deleted

For example: `8c8,9` means that line number 8 in the first file (`--from-file`) has changed to *something* and this *something* is stored in the lines 8-9 in the second file. Similarly `2d1` means that line 2 from the first file has been deleted, expected after line 1 in the second file, etc.

I don't think you really want to get rid of those codes, they are quite useful, but if you insist on removing them (or changing to something else), then just play with the following six output formats (here I assume you are using GNU diff):

- `--old-line-format`
- `--new-line-format`
- `--old-group-format`
- `--new-group-format`
- `--changed-group-format`
- `--unchanged-group-format`

I will not cover all details of the (rather complex) syntax here, you will find their description in the `info diff` under *If-then-else* chapter. The bellow will give you exactly what you are asking, i.e. no codes at all, just pure `<` and `>`:

```
diff --old-line-format=$'< %l\n' --new-line-format=$'> %l\n' \
     --old-group-format=$'%<' --new-group-format=$'%>' \
     --changed-group-format=$'%>' --unchanged-group-format='' file1 file2
```

You can make alias of that if you want.

Comment: I feel that if the OP wants a crippled diff, other tools like comm might be an option, instead of attempting to bend diff to their will?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the comm option. It worked like a charm. I used:
`comm -3 file2.txt file.txt`